# How can I determine the language from a DFA?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language, context-free-grammar

I was given three DFAs to solve.

[image]

I understand the first one is a*. I think the second one would be b*(a+)*.
I cannot figure out what the third one would be, it seems like there are too many different possibilities. The ones I came up with have too many conditions and it doesn't seem right.
Is there an easy way to determine the language?

Answer (score 1):

I got $((b+ab)(ab)^*(b+aa)+aa)(a+b)^*=(b+ab)(ab)^*(b+aa)(a+b)^*+a^2(a+b)^*$

There is a very famous technique called State Elimination Method to convert DFA's to regular expressions.

Comment: How can there be an a^2? Does that mean a{2}?
Can you explain each section of your regex? I can't match it to the DFA

Comment: No I meant $a^2=aa$ only. I don't know what is $a\{2\}$.

Comment: Beginning at the start state, the $(b+ab)$ part takes you to the the bottom state for the first time. After this, $(ab)^*$ means you will still remain in the bottom state. Then, $(b+aa)$ takes you to the final state for the first time. Using $(a+b)^*$, we will stay in the final state.                                   
                                                                                  In the other case, beginning at the start state, $aa$ takes you to the final state for the first time. Using $(a+b)^*$, we will stay in the final state.